# Simultaneous Linear Equations with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following simultaneous equations
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} \mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{dt}^{2}}-\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{dt}}=2 \mathrm{x}+2 \mathrm{t}, \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{dt}}+4 \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{y}}{\mathrm{dt}}=3 \mathrm{y}
$$
I tried but I was not able eliminate neither x nor y.
I tried by differentiating the 2nd equation and finding $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} \mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{dt}^{2}}$.

Comment: My advice would be to introduce a third variable $z = \frac{dx}{dt},$ rewrite the $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ as $\frac{dz}{dt},$ and then solve using the normal first-order system eigenvalue method. Do you know how to solve a first-order linear system of the form $\vec{r}' = A\vec{r} + \vec{g}(t)$?

Comment: why don't multiply the 1st by 4 and then sum them?

Comment: @janmarqz if we multiply the 1st by 4 and add then 3y rmains in the result and we don't need y in the final LDE.

Comment: Also the Laplace Transform could help...

Comment: ah! ok, then follow the Stephen advice

Comment: @StephenDonovan could you please provide the solution. I tried but its not happening.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have time to at the moment, I might be able to later though. If you're not familiar with the process I could drop a quick link if that would help

Comment: @StephenDonovan yes please!

Comment: Okay, well you can find some of the general process for how to go about solving the first-order system here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolutionsToSystems.aspx. More details are available on other pages on that website. You can also look at my answer here for an example worked through in detail: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971044/solving-linear-differential-systems/3971242#3971242